# Make Safari not stop playing video when existing to home screen?

Tags: ipad, safari, video

On Android, I use FireFox and its "Video Background Play Fix" extension. This makes FireFox keep playing the audio of the YouTube video I was watching, even if I exit to the home screen or turn off the phone's screen.

With Safari on iPadOS, it seems that Safari stops the video if I exit to home screen. However, the video is actually paused in the notification area (swipe down), so if I click the play button, Safari plays the video in the background, just like FireFox on Android.

But of course, clicking the play button again and again each time I exit to home screen is annoying. Is there any setting or extension to make Safari not stop playing?